# To what extent are ethical questions okay for this SE?

Tags: discussion

I am concerned that [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30149/to-a-wesleyan-what-is-marriage) may be inappropriate to the Stack Exchange, because it asks for Wesleyan ethics, even though it is known that people can reason differently in ethical decision-making. Also, as the Wesleyan Quadrilateral holds Reason, it is assumed that Reason is used in biblical hermeneutics and ethics. So, hypothetically, two Wesleyans can reason differently and both claim that they are derived from Wesleyan thought. What to do in this case? Do we allow ethical questions?

(The reason I hold the opinion that it is an ethical question is that the description seems to ask for what qualifies or not qualifies as a "Wesleyan marriage", as if somehow the Wesleyan marriage is different from other types of Christian marriages. Wouldn't rejecting a marriage as valid contribute to Wesleyan ethics, that is, how should the Christian behave in the world based on his/her understanding of what God wants?)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's much different between these and other questions. If you're asking for a definitive ethical answer that's a Truth question. If you're asking what ethical beliefs a Christian group has and someone can show where it's documented, then great.

Comment: Well, a well-documented ethical position is that Jehovah's Witnesses reject blood transfusions, because--I forget what's the justification is. In any case, the important thing is that there has been medical advances, which allows for alternatives to blood transfusions, so that people with a religious objection to it or people who are concerned about health risks may opt for them. That would be an interesting Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

I see this as a straight theology question: In Wesleyan theology, what are the defining characteristics of a marriage? As far as to what extent ethical questions can be asked, I'd say that as long as it can be focused on a given set of denominations and backed up by references, it should be fine.