# Are overview ethics questions ok?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

This is based on this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79949/how-best-for-a-christian-to-explore-the-ethics-of-a-covid-19-vaccine-that-might) which while I believe is a good question, I don't believe is a good fit for this site, but maybe I don't understand the rules as well as I believe since a mod commented that it was a good question.

IMO:

- Is asking about the ethics of all Christianity (different denominations have different beliefs on vaccines so there will be differing ethics depending on who you ask, [Christian ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_ethics)...too broad)
- Is asking about vaccines (different denominations have different opinions on vaccines, [Immunization and Religion](https://www.vumc.org/health-wellness/news-resource-articles/immunizations-and-religion)...too broad)
- Is asking about the ethics of abortion in one sense (again different denominations have different opinions on abortion, [Where major religious groups stand on abortion](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/06/21/where-major-religious-groups-stand-on-abortion/)...too broad)
- title mentions how best for a Christian to explore the ethics of ... (best is subjective, and different denominations would have different approaches...opinion based)

I'd like iterate that I believe this is a good question, but as it is stated I feel like it is off topic for this site. Is this question off topic or not and why?

related:

- [To what extent are ethical questions okay for this SE?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/to-what-extent-are-ethical-questions-okay-for-this-se) - but this is not about an overview question
- [Are overview questions okay?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3645/are-overview-questions-okay) - basically it depends

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more like Biblical Basis questions than overview questions. If there's a known doctrinal reason for X ethical principle (in this case using aborted babies to culture vaccines) in set of Y faith traditions (Catholics for sure, hopefully others), it's like saying there's a known doctrinal reason for M dogmatic principle (i.e. The Real Presence of Christ in the Eucharist) in the set of N faith traditions (i.e. Catholic, Orthodox).  And you could ask those questions under the guise of [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) without calling out the denominations (although it usually helps).